# Determine if logged in via iframe on a static jekyll blog

Tags: authentication, iframe, jekyll

I am trying to build an e-learning style site similar to KhanAcademy.org.  I'd like to be able to use Jekyll for the main site on www.mydomain.com.  In addition, I'd like a logged in view for the user as well which would live on learn.mydomain.com.  I am trying to figure out how to do a redirect on www.mydomain.com (jekyll blog) and redirect the user to the subdomain if they're logged in.  The one approach I can think of is to embed an iframe, and assert if the user is logged in and then do a redirect..Not sure if that's possible or would I need to communicate with the jekyll blog using postMessage()?

I really like this setup as I can start creating static content in a nice way on the main site, and if the user decides to then create an account and/or subscribe (pay) they will be redirected to the logged in user experience which I can build on a separate stack (node, express, react).  Appreciate the help and any ideas on how to implement this.  I plan on using auth0 for the logged in experience.